# error loading @sparticuz/chromium-min from s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless

I'm trying to use pupeteer in a lamda function with @sparticuz/chromium-min hosting the brotli files in an S3 bucket...
I create the S3 bucket via serverless framework and then upload the .tar file manually thorough the console.
I keep getting an "Unexpected end of data" error when running the function.

this is from my serverless.yml :

```
iam:
    role:
      statements:
         - Effect: 'Allow'
           Action:
            - s3:*
           Resource: !GetAtt ChromiumBucket.Arn
resources:
  Resources:
    ChromiumBucket:
      Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
      Properties:
        BucketName: chromium-pupeteer-bucket 
        CorsConfiguration:
          CorsRules:
          - AllowedMethods:
            - GET
            - POST
            - PUT
            AllowedOrigins:
            - "*"
            AllowedHeaders:
            - "*"
functions: 
  createPDF:
    handler: src/pdf/pdf.handler
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /pdf
          method: post
```

and the function:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-core");
const chromium = require("@sparticuz/chromium-min");

module.exports.handler = async (event) => {
  console.log("we got this far")
  const { pdfUrl } = JSON.parse(event.body)
  console.log(pdfUrl)
  const chromiumPackUrl = "https://bucket-name.s3.region.amazonaws.com/file.tar"
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      args: chromium.args,
      defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
      executablePath: await chromium.executablePath(chromiumPackUrl),
      headless: chromium.headless,
      ignoreHTTPSErrors: true
    });
console.log(browser)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your S3 is public? I had that problem and I solved it by changing the privacy of the bucket